# Which Android SDK for multi-version support?

Tags: android

If I want to develop an app for API 7 through to 18.  I understand I should set `minSdkVersion` to 7 in the manifest, and I assume I should set 18 as `targetSdkVersion`.  But I'm confused by what SDK I should use for development.  Should I be using the SDK for 2.1 (API 7) or 4.3 (API 18)?  I don't want compatibility behaviours as I want to completely control and specify what to do on each platform version.  And what about the support library?  Would I use support libraries 8-18 or 1-7?

(Posted here because development questions are off-topic for android.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is there any reason why you are trying to support `API 7`? `98%` of android users now are on `API 10` and above http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html (That can access the play store)

Comment: does it change the answer if i change the question?

Comment: No, just set the min API higher. So you have access to more functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can and should use the newest SDK. Eclipse or Intellij will automatically take care of letting you know if you are attempting to use a component that is only available in newer APIs. You will only want to use support library v7 and below since you intend on supporting API 7 and above. A lot of your worries will automatically be taken care of by your IDE. It will let you know if you are trying to use things that are not available in your minimum API level (which you indicate in your manifest file).

Comment: Intellij 13's not flagging this line: `GeofenceHardwareRequest.createCircularGeofence(0.0,0.0,0.1);`

Comment: If you manually run the Android "lint" tool it should pick it up, unless the enclosing method or class has a `TargetApi(X)` annotation.

Comment: @Jayen I actually don't use Intellij right now and I can't say for sure why it's not flagging it automatically. One thing I do know for sure though is that Android Studio is still in early access preview which means there will be plenty of bugs.